# C# error: A new expression requires () or [] after type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in the Unity3D engine and I am just writing some simple code for jumping, I have came across this problem:

> Assets/jumpControll.cs(17,107): error CS1526: A new expression requires () or [] after type.

I am not sure how to fix it as I'm sure I am stating that jump height is a float, the error is in this line;

```
 transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y(jumpHeight 3.0f), transform.position.z);
```

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class jumpControll : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool jump;
    public float jumpHeight;




    // Use this for initialization

    public void SetTransformX (float jumpHeight) {

        jumpHeight = 3.0f;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y(jumpHeight 3.0f), transform.position.z);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        jump = !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
        if (jump == true)
            SetTransformX(jumpHeight);
    }
}
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me out, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

looks like you're trying to do multiplication here?

```
transform.position.y(jumpHeight 3.0f)
```

that won't work in C#, try:

```
transform.position.y * jumpHeight
```